# Error. Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2

Tags: spring-boot, maven, compiler-errors, weblogic

Please help, this error occurs when deploying the program to weblogicservice. I searched the Internet for solutions to the problem, there were not many of them, but they did not help. What should I add?

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project weblogic_users_REST_v1: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TKgn.png)

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic_users_REST_v1</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>weblogic_users</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!--<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>Internal repo</name>
            <url>file:///home/thara/testesb/in</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>-->
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ldap/spring-ldap-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>19.6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


   <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven-deploy-plugin is a plugin to deploy your artifact to a remote artifact repository. This plugin needs those references that you are mentioning from the error messages.

You say you try to deploy to an application server, Weblogic, maybe you intended to use a maven plugin such as [weblogic-maven-plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#CHEEGDBD)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To be honest, I don't know. I came to this project to fix a bug, I cloned the project from git. Previous colleagues who developed this application quit. No one can really explain to me what's what here, I have to figure it out myself. And then there are such errors during deployment appeared.
In the description of the problem, I added my pom.xml, you can see it above

Comment: Well maven is mostly related to building the artifact, in your case the .war file. Then various plugins will deal with deployment and such. You mention during deployment, so I think I need more information regarding what commands the deployment are executing, it sounds like there is some kind of deployment system in place. Either you provide/update the details for the remote repository, so the deploy-lifecycle is satisfied, or you just build the artifact with mvn package, to get your .war file and upload it to the app server (if no deployment pipelines or similar are in place).